# Google Chrome crashing when opening youtube

Tags: windows-10, google-chrome, youtube, progressive-web-app

I am using Chrome 92.0.4515.107 on Win 10. Whenever I try to open youtube (i.e. type the address in omnibox and press Enter), Chrome instantly closes. When I reopen Chrome, it warns that it was closed improperly and offers to restore tabs. It seems so fast that the app is probably only loaded from the cache at that point, not through the internet.

I also had the same issue when just typing it in the omnibox — whenever I wrote even a "y" in omnibox and Youtube appeared in suggestions, Chrome crashed. I solved this by removing some (latest 500 or so) youtube entries from the history. Now the omnibox works fine, but I still can't navigate to the site.

What I tried without success:

- Updating Chrome (it was Chrome 91 before).
- Uninstalling and reinstalling Chrome.
- Disabling extensions.

I think this might be related to some workers, permissions or some PWA stuff gone wrong. Maybe there is a way to purge "workers and other PWA stuff" of some site without navigating to that site? (And without purging everything for every other site, of course)

#### Update 1

The issue is not present in incognito mode

#### Update 2

I opened `chrome://apps/` and removed youtube, it did not help.

Comment: There have been several updates for Windows 10 and Chrome since July 2021. Do you still have this problem?

Answer (score -1):

in chrome: three dots on top right/ settings/ search engine(on left menu)/ manage search engines/ cick on the three dots to the right of google, then 'edit'/ copy and paste 'url with %s in place of query' link into notepad.
here's what mine says, for comparison:
{google:baseURL}search?q=%s&{google:RLZ}{google:originalQueryForSuggestion}{google:assistedQueryStats}{google:searchFieldtrialParameter}{google:iOSSearchLanguage}{google:prefetchSource}{google:searchClient}{google:sourceId}{google:contextualSearchVersion}ie={inputEncoding}

otherwise, remove and re-add google to the search engines, or choose another search engine.

hi, and good luck!!

Answer (score -1):

You should click the 3 dots, open history and clear you cache and cookie, make sure to check the extra box that clears cookies.